# VIM finding words in code repository

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a VIM function that will allow me to find words in my code repository
by using the external grep function of linux then highlight all occurences of that word.

Also the silent on the execute is suppose to be suppressing the output of the external program but it is not working..

```
set grepprg=grep\ -rns\ -C\ 1\ "
set grepformat=%f:%l:%m

function! WordFind()
    let l:word = input("Find:")
    execute 'silent grep ' . l:word . ' .'
    :redraw!
    :copen
    execute '/' . l:word
endfunction
```

Comment: Have you looked at `:h vimgrep`?

Comment: yup.. but I dont use vimgrep it seems to be slower than grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for words or symbols? If you are looking for symbols (functions, variables, arrays...) you might find ctags and/or cscope to be a better fit.

See :help tags for more information.

But... you didn't ask anything so, what do you want from us? A code critique?

The last line of your function seems useless because every line in the quickfix window contains your word at least once. It will just move the cursir horizontally on the first line which is of no use.

I would use :cwindow instead of :copen.

Other than that, your function seems ok.

EDIT

Well no, it is not OK, the last line wouldn't work anyway. The revised function below works for me using your `grepprg` and `grepformat` settings:

```
function! WordFind()
    let l:word = input("Find:")
    execute 'silent grep ' . l:word . ' .'
    redraw!
    cwindow
    wincmd p
    let @/ = l:word
endfunction
```

The `wincmd p` line may not be necessary after all.

I don't believe the output of `grep` can be completely hidden in CLI Vim.

Comment: oh.. shoot the comment on the code block was not included on my post. anyway my problem is on the end of the function I am trying to highlight all occurence of the word I search for but that does not work.

Comment: You'd need to change to the active window, with wincmd p, before doing that search.

Comment: ok i tried to insert ':wincmd p' after the :cwindow line.. but still does not do the highlight thing..

Comment: See my edit, that line may not be necessary as I think I didn't completely get what you wanted.